# how to have some contexts all over a project?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to have a team model and i want to have access to its fields all over my project like how you use `{{user.username}}` wherever you want.
down here I've put my team model.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User)
    coin = models.IntegerField(default=50000)
    gem = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    motivation = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    fans_satisfaction = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Any helps are appreciated, thank you

Comment: All the values for what instance of Team though? It makes sense for User, because the specific user is logged in. Which team would you show?

Comment: What you mean by *all over your project*? can you explain more about what your want? you can add a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question about what you want to do!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to get a team's coin, gem and name by putting '{{team.coin}}' for example in any of my templates

Comment: @Kasra I mean all my templates obviously!

Comment: But *which* team? You'll presumably have more than one in your database. Which one do you want to appear when you do that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The one belonging to logged in user. every team has a User field called manager if you have noticed.

Comment: The only thing I see is that each *team* has a *user* (manager)...but not that each *user* has a *team*...There's a difference.

Comment: @rnevius You're right I'm just a newbie in django. I've noticed the same thing i just don't know how to add a team to django's default User model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) in a module `myapp.context_processors.py`

```
def team(request):
    team = None
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        try:
            # fetch the team managed by the logged in user
            team = Team.objects.get(manager=request.user)
        except (Team.DoesNotExist, Team.MultipleObjectsReturned):
            pass
    return {'team': team}
```

Add `myapp.context_processors.team` to your list of context processors in your settings. Then, in your templates you can access `{{ team }}`.

Comment: Nice, but you did a filter, which will never trigger a DoesNotExist. And it could be length is 0 or more than 1. If you change it into a get, add a except for multiple objects returned.

Comment: @Nima, this answer and the one of @Daniel Roseman are both right, but be aware of the difference. By adding a context processor you will call this "query"  everytime you load a template. But it is only once per template. If you use Daniels solution you will do a query per use. So if you use Daniels solution, use it as followed; `{% with user.team_set.all as team %}`. You could replace `.all` with `.first`.

Comment: @Blackeagle52 If there is only one team per user, then I think the correct approach would be a one-to-one field instead of a foreign key. You would have to handle users without a team though.

Comment: @Blackeagle52 I took another approach.I use manager class to take team for a user.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it in your templates write a context processor.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

If you want to have it on request, you have to write your own middleware.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything special. As you say, Team has a ForeignKey to User: that means you can always access the user's teams wherever you have a user:

```
{{ user.team_set.all }}
```

Note that, contrary to what you say, there is no single team for a user: an FK in that direction means one user can have *many* teams.